# How to get data from rest api and save JSON to txt file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, save, urllib3

I am trying to get some data from a rest api and save a JSON to a txt-file. Here is what I do:

```
#random rest api
a = 'https://thiswouldbemyurl.com'

#urllib3 + poolmanager for requests
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

import json
r = http.request('GET', a)
json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I get an error already with `json.load`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is how the JSON looks like

```
{
   "success":true,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":26,
         "name":"A",
         "comment":"",
         "start_time_plan":null,
         "start_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "start_time_delta":null,
         "start_time_score":null,
         "start_time_score_achievement":null,
         "start_time_traffic_light":null,
         "end_time_plan":null,
         "end_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "end_time_delta":null,
         "end_time_score":null,
         "end_time_score_achievement":null,
         "end_time_traffic_light":null,
         "status":0,
         "measure_schedule_revision_id":63,
         "responsible_user_id":3,
         "created_time":"2016-09-13 11:29:14",
         "created_user_id":3,
         "modified_time":"2016-09-21 16:33:41",
         "modified_user_id":3,
         "model":"Activity"
      }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get the error with  `json.loads`. This is it: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Sounds like the URL you're downloading does not return valid JSON. Calling `json.loads(...)` on something that is not JSON will not work. In the future, please include the errors in your question. :)

Comment: Sorry, I just used a random URL. I indeed get a JSON (see edit above). What might be the problem here?

Comment: If that's the full output, then that's not valid JSON. It's missing a closing `}`, for example.

Comment: @shazow It's not. Just the begining. Goes in forever that thing...

Comment: The error you posted indicates that the JSON is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to `json.load(...)` something that is not actually JSON.

Looking at the URL you're using, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/` returns HTML rather than JSON.

If you use something like `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` which *does* return JSON, then that particular error should go away.

Comment: Sorry, I just used a random URL. I indeed get a JSON (see edit above). What might be the problem here?